# How to navigate fragment without adding it into backstack with NavController?

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

`NavController` has methods `navigate` which navigate by default with backstack. How to navigate to the fragment without having backstack?
Please note that, I am not asking about `FragmentTransaction`

Comment: just dont call `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);`

Comment: I am not using `fragmentTransaction`

Comment: Then post at least part of your codes

Answer (score 7):

If you have a back stack of:

```
A -> B
```

And want to get to a back stack of

```
A -> C
```

You can do a 'replace' operation by popping B off the back stack and adding C.

In Navigation, this is done by using `app:popUpTo` (and optionally `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` if needed) to the `<action>` in your XML or by using the equivalent `NavOptions` API.

```
<action
  android:id="@+id/goToC"
  app:destination="@+id/c"
  app:popUpTo="@+id/b"
  app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
    setOf(
        R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
        R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send
    ), drawerLayout
)

setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //----------- Pop Back Stack
    navController.popBackStack()
    //---------------------------

    navController.navigate(it.itemId)
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers()

    true
}
```