# Better way to pass data between Fragments Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

Passing data between Fragments in Navigation Component is easy. Say going from `A` to `B` you just set `arguments` with `SafeArgs` and you are done.

But, it gets tricky when passing data from `B` back to `A`.

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing), we can use `SharedViewModel` which is works well. But I am looking for better way of passing data back to `A` from `B`.

The problem of using `SharedViewModel` is, you have to create `SharedViewModel` for every fragment pair that you need to pass data.

Any suggestions? If any annotation-processing method you can think about, you are more than welcome to recommend.

Comment: I think, there is no better way to do it. We also used `SharedViewModel` in order to overcome. `Navigation SafeArgs` could be used to pass data from A to B but when it is from B to A, a `ViewModel` seems to be a better way. You can also check out PublishSubject/BehaviorSubject that allows each destination to listen to the latest value.

Comment: @nuhkoca musooff sorry if this is little bit out of topic. but I am a beginner. if I use SharedViewModel then I will have 2 viewModels in a fragment ? in FragmentA, I will have FragmentAViewModel and SharedViewModel, and in FragmentB, I will have FragmentBViewModel and SharedViewModel ? so the the shared view model only to pass the data back to previous fragment ?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `SharedViewModel` way, you can follow the next approach:

****1-** Define a delegate** for your `Details Fragment`. (This delegate have to implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`:

```
interface DetailsFragmentDelegate: Serializable {
    fun onSomething1(someData1: SomeData1)
    fun onSomething2(someData2: SomeData2)
}
```

2- **Add the delegate** to your `Details Fragment` arguments in `nav_graph.xml`

3- **Pass the delegate** to your `Details Fragment` when navigating to its destination by your `Base Fragment`:

```
findNavController().navigate(
    BaseFragmentDirections.actionBaseFragmentToDetailsFragment(
        object: DetailsFragmentDelegate {
            // override delegate methods

        }
    )
)
```

4- **Get the delegate** argument in `Details Fragment` and pass the data back wherever you need:

```
....
delegate.onSomething1(data1)
....
delegate.onSomething2(data2)
....
```

I am not sure whether there is a better way or not, but **it's working...**

Comment: Thanks, passing a Serializable interface is a good idea for passing arguments when you have more complex data

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a ViewModel per Fragment pair. What I am doing is creating a ViewModel per Fragment. Each ViewModel would have a map[Class[Fragment], Any] named mailBox.

Each Fragment will define a FragmentResult type which is different per Fragment class.

In the child Fragment **onBackPressedHandler**, before pop-up, fetch the parent ViewModel from the Activity and put your result in the mailBox for your class. You will need a ViewModel class for that. See below.

The parent Fragment needs to pass it's ViewModel.class to the child Fragment, before launching it.

When the Parent Fragment is re-started after popping up the child from the stack. Get the mailBox map from it's ViewModel, check if there is a key with value from the expected FragmentChild::class. If so, then cast to the desired type.

The parent Fragment ViewModel needs to save who was the last child it launched.

Answer (score -1):

I am using an callback interface for this. So i have created an interface with some methods. I implemented that interface 'A' and then call if from 'B'. Very easy and works great.

Comment: @LMaker: sorry for the late relpy but here some code

Create an interface (File->New->Java Class->Kind = interface)

`public interface FragmentDataPassListener {
    void doSomeThing(String parameterA);
}`

Comment: extended my Activity like this

`public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDataPassListener {

// normal activity methodes here
   ...

// put the overrides of your interface here

  @Override
  public void doSomeThing(String parameterA) {
  }
}`

Comment: Then in my fragment i do this.

`@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);
try {
mCallback = (FragmentDataPassListener) context;
}
catch (ClassCastException e)
{
throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()+ " must implement FragmentDataPassListener in GPSmapFragment");
}
}`

Now i can use mCallback in my fragment to execute the methods in the Activity
by just `calling mCallback.doSomeThing("Test");`

Comment: Don't do that !!. it will cause a Memory Leaks and this Approach is not recommended.