# I used navigation in my app,How can I launch a Fragment for which I get a result when it finished?

Tags: android, navigation

I have two Fragments Fragment1 and Fragment2,In Fragment1 I use findNavController().navigate() launch the Fragment2,When Fragment2 finished,How to pass the data to Fragment1?(Translate by Google)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243119/pass-data-back-to-previous-fragment-using-android-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getParentFragment()` in Fragment2 to transfer data to Fragment1. This only works if you create Fragment2 via `getChildFragmentManager()` of Fragment1.

If you use `getSupportFragmentManager()` of `Activity` then you have to create a listener.

```
class Fragment2 {
    private UpdateFragment1Listener updateFragment1Listener;

    void sendDataToFragment1() {
        updateFragment1Listener.updateFragment(myData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof UpdateFragment1Listener ) {
            updateFragment1Listener = (UpdateFragment1Listener ) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement UpdateFragment1Listener ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        updateFragment1Listener = null;
    }

    interface UpdateFragment1Listener {
        void updateFragment1(MyData myData);
    }
}

class MyActivity implements Fragment2.UpdateFragment1Listener {
    private Fragment1 fragment1;

    @Override
    void updateFragment1(MyData myData) {
        fragment1.update(myData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want an official solution, not an interface. Thank you all the same. Now I used EventBus to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't know how official you want it to be but the interface solution literally comes from Android Studio itself. But yeah EventBus should work.