# how to navigate back to previous fragment using navigation component while sending data?

Tags: android, fragment, android-architecture-navigation

I have  4 Fragments , A, B,C.Fragment A will be the main Fragment, I will be navigating from fragment A to Fragment B then Fragment B return with a result to fragment A. Then I will navigate To fragment C from fragment A, and fragment c will do some operations and return a result to fragment A. Each time the fragment A will show and keep the result returned from each fragment

The navigation between fragment A to the other fragment  is implemented using this code

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putBoolean("data", true)
findNavController().navigate(R.id.myAction, toVoicePassphraseRecognitionbundle)
```

My problem her is that to return to fragment A, i also use findNavController().navigate()but doing so will create a new fragment that will be added to the stack, so my question is how can i navigate back from fragment B to A, or C to A while keeping the view state as it is without creating a new Fragment A.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass data back to previous fragment using Android Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243119/pass-data-back-to-previous-fragment-using-android-navigation)

Comment: the question is the same, but there s no detailed or explained solution that may be used

Comment: findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.a_fragment, false) I think you can use this to achieve your goal

Comment: I use `findNavController(...).navigateUp()` to navigate to the previous fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are setting `Fragment A` as destination in your action,
what it does is, it creates a new instance of the `Fragment`.

What you really want is to `go back to`, not `go to`.

So what we we do to go back, we pop our back stack.

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
    android:name="com.sample.project.FragmentC"
    android:label="FragmentC">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/navigate_C_to_A"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentA"
        app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
</fragment>
```

`popUpTo` is where you want to land

`popUpToInclusive` means do you want this fragment to pop from stack too?

And let say your flow is like A->B->C->A

But `Fragment A` is unknown, or `B` and `C` are the part of flow that can be used at many places, so the `A` will not be `A` every time.

In that case :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
    android:name="com.sample.project.FragmentC"
    android:label="FragmentC">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/navigate_C_to_before_B"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentB"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</fragment>
```

`popUpToInclusive` is the key here